# How to solve this parametric linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric

How to solve this parametric linear equation? I need to find all numbers for $\alpha$ with which has a single, infinity or none solution.

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    2\alpha & \alpha & 1 & 4 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right]
$$

I end up with this and don't know how to remove 2 from bottom row to have zeros bellow the diagonal.

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & \alpha-2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you see how to proceed with row reduction? Different cases arise according to value of $\alpha$, depending on whether or not $\alpha=2$

Comment: So I should change $\alpha$ to some interesting numbers (2, 4 and e.g. 5) and continue with gaussian elimination from that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything, consider the case of $\alpha = 0$.  Note that in this case, we can't get a pivot in the first column, and the system is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Reduce further to show that this will yield no solutions.

Now, following your steps, you've reached
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & \alpha-2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right]
$$
proceed by breaking the problem into two cases.  The first (and easier) case is when $\alpha - 2 = 0$ (which is to say $\alpha = 2$).  We have 
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
  \end{array}\right]
$$
which you can see leads to a unique solution.

Otherwise, we have
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & \alpha-2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right] \to \\
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1/(\alpha-2) & 2/(\alpha-2) \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right]
$$
If $\alpha \neq 4$, we will have a unique solution.

Otherwise, the system reads as
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1/2 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2
  \end{array}\right]
$$
verify that this system yields infinitely many solutions.

Comment: For $\alpha = 2$ there is no solution (2y = 0), is that right?

Comment: For $\alpha = 2$, we have the unique solution $x =1/2 ,y=0, z = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The elementary row operations you performed are valid and don't change the solution set. You can do another one, though: swap rows 2 and 3, so you get
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & \alpha-2 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now sum to the third row the second row multiplied by $-(\alpha-2)/2$, getting
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    \alpha & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{4-\alpha}{2} & 4-\alpha \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now you can clearly see that, for $\alpha\ne0$ and $\alpha\ne4$, the system has unique solution (rank $3$ of the incomplete matrix). For $\alpha=4$, the system has infinitely many solutions. It remains to see what happens for $\alpha=0$:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}\right]\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}\right]\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
So, no solution.